# Android application not crashing when it should [ACRA]

Tags: android, toast, crash-reports, acra

Hi all,

I'm using (trying at the moment) [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) for bug-reporting. Scenario is:

- I open the app: ACRA outputs `ACRA is enabled for mypackage, intializing...`
- I enter the Settings (where I prepared a NullpointerException)
- The app freezes and *Preparing crash dialog* is output via a toast
- The app does **not** close, but instead outputs the same toast again and again (all Views are gone)
- When I close the app, after a few seconds (of gathering data I guess) the crash dialog opens

I have the following Annotation in front of my Application subclass:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "iwontshowyoumyformkey", customReportContent = {
    REPORT_ID, APP_VERSION_CODE, ANDROID_VERSION, PHONE_MODEL, BRAND,
    STACK_TRACE }, 
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG, 
    resToastText = R.string.acra_toast_text, 
    resDialogText = R.string.acra_dialog_text, 
    resDialogTitle = R.string.acra_dialog_title,
    resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.acra_dialog_comment_prompt,
    resDialogOkToast = R.string.acra_dialog_ok_toast,
    forceCloseDialogAfterToast=true)
```

A notable detail is that the error occurs again and again, according to the Logcat.
This made me think that the activity is restarted all the time, and the error is in onCreate...
**But** the fact that the tag is *ACRA* made me unsure if it isnt ACRA, reoutputting the error.

---

**Problem**: The app should be crashed and closed so that the dialog can appear, but isn't.
**Question**: How would I go about debugging/solving this? A solution would be even better...

Thank you in advance,
Till

Comment: _This seems like a nice problem to have ;]_

Comment: Its not as nice as it sounds, because you can't use the app in this state. Its more of _half-crashed_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not solved, but I decided to not spend any more time on it, and abandon ACRA.
[Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) has proven to be quite painless.